# Get style of excel cell with Epplus

Tags: c#, excel, openxml-sdk, epplus

Is there any way to get the style of a specific cell with open xml sdk and epplus?

Currently I'm getting the value in the following way:

```
currentWorksheet.Cells[nRowId, 3].Text.Trim();
```

In adittion to this I want if there is a background color, and a border.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try

```
currentWorksheet.Cells[nRowId, 3].Style;
```

Also:

```
currentWorksheet.Cells[nRowId, 3].Style.Fill.BackgroundColor;
currentWorksheet.Cells[nRowId, 3].Style.Border;
```